# NP++: Regular expression

Tags: expression, notepad++

I have a text with many expressions like this <.....>, e.g.:

> <..> Text1 <.sdfdsvd> Text 2 <....dgdfg> Text3 <...something> Text4

How can I eliminate now all brackets <...> and all commands/texts between these brackets? But the other "real" text between these (like text1, text2 above) should not be touched.

I tried with the regular expression:

> <.*>

But this finds also a block like this, including the inbetween text:

> <..> Text1 <.sdfdsvd>

My second try was to search for alle expressions <.> without a third bracket between these two, so I tried:

> <.*[^>^<]>

But that does not work either, no change in behavior. How to construct the needed expression correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Notepad++:

Find what: `<[^>]+?>`

Replace with: *nothing*

Try it out: http://regex101.com/r/lC9mD4

There are a few problems with your attempt: `<.*[^>^<]>`

- `.*` matches all characters up through the *final* possible match. This means that *all tags except the last* will be bypassed. This is called [greedy](https://www.google.com/search?q=greedy%20possessive%20reluctant%20quantifiers). In my solution, I have changed it to possessive, which goes up to the *first* possible match: `.*?`...although I apply this to the character class itself: `[^>]+?`.
- `[^>^<]` is incorrect for two reasons, one small, one big. The small reason is that the first caret `^` says "do not match any of the following characters", and the characters following it are `>`, `^`, and `<`. So you are saying you don't want to match the caret character, which is incorrect (but not harmful). The larger problem is that this is attempting to match *exactly one character*, when it needs to be one or more, which is signified by the plus sign: `[^><]+`.

Otherwise, your attempt is not that far off from my solution.

Comment: Thanks, and a similar question: How can I replace in NP++ a regular expression by itself with some modification? E.g. I have a text with many numbers between the sentences. Now I want to replace each number by itself and a line-break.

If I try something like [0-9] replace by [0-9]\r\n -> that does not work. How to store the found regular expression as a variable and to replace it with a modification (like added linebreak or something like that)?

Comment: Likely, this should work: Find what: `\b([0-9]+)` (or `\b(\d+)`), Replace with: `$1\r\n`. Consider adding all questions to your original question-post, or in an entirely-new question, as it is not recommended to ask additional unrelated questions of your answer-ers.

Comment: @Mustafa Look into `()` and `\1`, `\2`, etc. You'll want something like `([0-9])` for your search and `\1\r\n` for your replace.

Comment: As I understand it, back-references such as `\1` are generally used in the regex itself, not in the replace-with term. Capture groups are used in the replace-with: `$1`. Both do work in NotePad++, however.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
<[^\s]*>
```

It looks for a left bracket, then anything that isn't whitespace between the brackets, then a right bracket. It would need some adjusting if there's whitespace between the brackets (`<text1 text2>`), though, and at that point a modification of one of your attempts would work better:

```
<[^<^>]*>
```

This one looks for a left bracket, then anything that isn't a left bracket or right bracket, then a right bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<.*?>`. If you don't use the "?", regular expressions will try to find the *longest* string that matches. Using "*?" will force to find the *shortest*.